# How do I add data to a database in Delphi by using edits instead of a DBNavigator?

Tags: delphi

My interface is very basic. It just includes edits for the user to input data into a database, when they click the button i want it to add the data into my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this.

- Go to the `Data Controls` tab of the Component palette.
- Select a `TDBEdit` and place it on the same form as your DBNavigator.  The IDE will name this `DBEdit1`
- Set the `Datasource` property of your `DBEdit1` to the same datasource as your DBNavigator.
- Set the `DataField` property of `DBEdit1` to the name of a field in your dataset.
- Compile and run.

That's it.  Leave your DBNavigator on your form because you will find that when you make a change to the contents of DBEdit1, its `Save` and `Cancel` buttons automatically enable to let you save or cancel the change.

Also, you'll find that if you click your DBNavigator's '+' button, which begins the insertion of a new record into your table, you can then type the field values for the new record into your DBEdits.

**Don't** use normal non-DB-aware `TEdit` components and a dynamically-created Sql statement which concatenates the `TEdits`'s contents with other Sql as suggested in the other answer which briefly appeared here and now seems to have been deleted - it is a waste of time, but much more importantly renders your app vulnerable to **Sql-Injection** - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.  By sending the server an unverified Sql statement which includes what the user has typed into a `TEdit`, you're effectively providing the user with an opportunity to type additional Sql statements into the `TEdit` and that is **exactly** how Sql injection can occur. On the other hand, when you use `TDBEdits`, the Sql for updating the database record is automatically generated by Delphi's `TDataSet` framework in a way which does not provide a similar opportunity for Sql Injection.

If some reason you absolutely have to generate your own Sql Update statements, to minimise the risk of Sql Injection, make sure that you use a *parameterised* Update statement, that is, one where the changed field values are specified as values of parameters in your TDataSet-descendant's `Parameters` object, rather than in the Update Sql itself.  An example of a parameterised Update statement might be:

```
Update MyTable set FieldA =:FieldA, FieldB=:FieldB where RowID =:RowID
```

where :FieldA, :FieldB and :RowID are the parameters.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with building your own SQL. Ultimately a DB aware control will do that. Parameters are the usual way to avoid injection.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I'm not saying that there is anything wrong with building your own Sql per se and of course you're correct that that will happen with db-aware controls somewhere in the TDataSet machinery.  Most TDataSet descendants I've come across automatically generate parameterised Update statements to post changes back to the DB anyway - see e.g. TClientDataSet's associated TSqlResolver. I will add a mention of parameters

Comment: You imply that when you say that forming SQL leaves you vulnerable to injection.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  For once I disagree with your good self.  I specifically began by "dynamically-created Sql statement which concatenates the TEdits's contents with other Sql".  I chose those words carefully and they say what I meant.

Comment: Thanks @MartynA for the answer, helped alot and program is running perfectly. Tried to upvote your answer but rep is not high enough for it to be public. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure that you need a coma in your SQL statement here: `MyTable, set`? It seems it should be: `UPDATE MyTable SET...`

Comment: @asd-tm:  Thanks for spotting that!  It was a typo, now fixed.